# If $\Omega$ is convex and bounded, then $C^1(\bar{\Omega})$ also convex?

Tags: continuity, convex-analysis

If $\Omega$ is a convex and bounded set, is then $C^1(\bar{\Omega})$ also convex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V := C^1(\Omega)$ is a vector space (i.e. scalar multiples and sums of functions in $V$ are still in $V$) , hence convex.